# changing the value of a fetched list array using react hook and controlled component

Tags: arrays, drop-down-menu, react-hooks, onchange, use-state

I'm kind on begiiner in programming....

I have an array of objects comes from state (array of Services that each service has id,name,price,size)

[{_id: "611921f7f82bf422a42d2604"
size: "Small - Less than 10kg"
name: "Bath & Tidy"
price: 65}
,

{_id: "611a9418aff2221e14c871f1"
size: "X-Large - 41kg+"
name: "Full service"
price: 160}
]

using filter and map,each time I get the pet size and filter only services related to that PET Size and shows in (select menu)...here's my code

```
const [selectedService, setSelectedService] = useState('')

  const onChangeHandler = (e) => {
    setSelectedService(e.target.value)
  }

//myPetArray is a dynamic list comes from (state)

     myPetArray.map((mypet) => (
              <Row className='pet-cart-container' key={mypet._id}>
                <Col xs={9} sm={9} md={9} lg={9}>
                  <h6>{mypet.petName}</h6>
                  <select
                    className='form-control'
                    value={selectedService}
                    onChange={onChangeHandler}
                  >
                    <option>select service base size</option>

//serviceList is full list of all services and 

//using filter I get only services related to pet size in loop

//using map each time  I create a select with related services for the current pet in loop

//for example if I have 5 pet I will have 5 select which each of them have 5 services

                    {serviceList
                      .filter((element) => {
                        return element.size === mypet.size
                      })

                      .map((service) => (
                        <option key={service._id} value={service.key}>
                          {service.name}
                          {service.price}
                        </option>
                      ))}
                  </select>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            ))
```

But the first problem is that I have no idea how to get the value of a changeable List ,(because number of pets is changing )and how to set their value into react useState hook.

the second problem is ,when I change one of dropdowns ,all the dropdowns with that size changing

[image: the second problem]

thanks you